# Reactjs state initialize an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to initialize an array of boolean values, where there is a different value on a specific position in array.

If I initialize state like this, empty is array.

```
state = {
    activeItems: [...new Array(5)].map((item, idx) =>
      idx === 1 ? true : false
    )
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain all necessary details.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The way `...` works is specific to your setup which isn't shown. It may work not as expected in TypeScript with downlevel iteration disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to first `fill` your array before mapping it :

```
state = {
    activeItems: new Array(5).fill().map((item, idx) => idx === 1)
}
```

```js
const result = new Array(5).fill().map((item, idx) => idx === 1)
console.log(result)
```

Also `idx === 1 ? true : false` can be reduced to `idx === 1` and deconstructing the array is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Array from gives you array with `<empty slots>`

Problem is because `map` do not iterate [over empty spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description)

```js
let arr = new Array(5)

let modified = arr.map((e,i)=> console.log(i)) // prints nothing
console.log('modifed prints nothing')
```

Fill empty state using fill

```js
let arr = new Array(5)

let modified = arr.fill(0).map((e,i)=> console.log(i))  //prints index
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you mentioned your code returns empty array. Because, it does return the expected output.

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead to avoid any inconsistency you currently have:

```js
const state = {
    activeItems: Array.from({length:5}, (_, idx) => idx === 1)
}

console.log(state)
```

The second parameter to `Array.from` is a `map` function.

Answer (score 1):

The code is workable out of the box in native ES6:

```
[...new Array(5)].map((item, idx) =>
  idx === 1 ? true : false
)
```

It results in

> [false, true, false, false, false]

array.

Any inconsistencies with it are caused by a transpiler in use and its implementation of `...` array spread syntax. In some implementations it may result in incompliant code, notably TypeScript with `downlevelIteration` compiler option disabled. For instance, it's used to in Stackblitz, even in JS projects. Without downlevel iteration, it would be transpiled to:

```
new Array(5).slice().map(function (item, idx) {
    return idx === 1 ? true : false;
});
```

`new Array(5).slice()` results in *sparse* array that won't be iterated with `map`. This situation can be secured by using `Array.from` or `Array.fill` (as other answers already suggest). Both will fill sparse array with `undefined` values that can be iterated with `map`:

```
Array.from(new Array(5)).map((item, idx) => idx === 1);

new Array(5).fill().map((item, idx) => idx === 1);
```